# jOOQ - How to pass columns and tables to functions?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, function, jooq

In my database I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE calibration_factor_pm1
(
sensor_id Integer REFERENCES sensor(id),
factor_a double precision NOT NULL,
factor_b double precision NOT NULL,
time_from_which_factor_is_used timestamp NOT NULL
)
```

And since there will be a few other tables like this one I want to make a function to which I can pass information about which factor (a or b) I want to fetch and from which table.

I was trying to do it this way:

```
private Double getCalibrationFactor(String sensorId, TableField<Record, TableImpl> factor, TableImpl PM, TableField<Record, TableImpl> sensorIdTableField, TableField<Record, TableImpl> timeFromWhichFactorIsUsed) {
        Double calibrationFactorAPM1 = 1.0;
        try {
            calibrationFactorAPM1 = Double.valueOf(Database.create
                    .select(factor) //CalibrationFactorPm1.CALIBRATION_FACTOR_PM1.FACTOR_A
                    .from(PM) //CalibrationFactorPm1.CALIBRATION_FACTOR_PM1
                    .where(sensorIdTableField.equal(Integer.valueOf(sensorId)))
                    .orderBy(timeFromWhichFactorIsUsed.desc())
                    .fetchOne()
                    .getValue(0)
                    .toString());
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Can't find calibration factor 'a' for this sensor");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

However, I get `Cannot resolve method 'equal(java.lang.Integer)'` on `.where(sensorIdTableField.equal(Integer.valueOf(sensorId)))` line.

How to approach this correctly?

@edit

This is what equal() expects:
[image: equal()'s expectations]

Comment: considering your schema, I suspect `equal` expects a `Double`, not an `Integer`. `sensorIdTableField.equal(Integer.valueOf(sensorId).doubleValue))` would probably work.

Comment: Nope, it's not working. Updated the question with an image showing what `equal` expects.

Comment: Ha sorry I read too fast - if you can change the signature of your method to use `Field<Integer> sensorIdTableField` it should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! It solved the problem with this line but now I get `Cannot resolve method 'orderBy(org.jooq.SortField<org.jooq.impl.TableImpl>)'` on `.orderBy(timeFromWhichFactorIsUsed.desc())` line.

Comment: I have posted an answer that should solve that new issue too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using more abstract types in your method signature, especially since you seem to know the types of the parameters passed to your method. That ways you can benefit from jooq's type safety features.

```
private Double getCalibrationFactor(String sensorId,
                                    Field<Double> factor,
                                    Table<?> PM,
                                    Field<Integer> sensorIdTableField,
                                    Field<Timestamp> timeFromWhichFactorIsUsed) {
  Record1<Double> calibrationFactorAPM1 = Database.create
              .select(factor) //CalibrationFactorPm1.CALIBRATION_FACTOR_PM1.FACTOR_A
              .from(PM) //CalibrationFactorPm1.CALIBRATION_FACTOR_PM1
              .where(sensorIdTableField.equal(Integer.valueOf(sensorId)))
              .orderBy(timeFromWhichFactorIsUsed.desc())
              .fetchOne();
  return calibrationFactorAPM1 == null ? calibrationFactorAPM1.value1() : 1d;
}
```

You may also want to pass an `Integer sensorId` instead of a `String sensorId`.

Comment: I get `Type 'org.jooq.util.xml.jaxb.Table' does not have type parameters` on `Table<?> PM` and what is `sql()`?

Comment: sorry sql() should be Database.create. The imports should be `import org.jooq.Field; import org.jooq.Table; import org.jooq.Record1;`

Comment: Thanks, it looks good now. I'll test it. BTW I get a warning: `Method invocation 'value1' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'` on line `return calibrationFactorAPM1 == null ? calibrationFactorAPM1.value1() : 1d;`.

Comment: @Defozo It can't happen if your DB column has a NOT NULL constraint but you should be able to get rid of the warning by changing `1d` into  `Double.valueOf(1d)`.

Comment: Also if the field is always called `sensor_id`, you could write `Field<Integer> sensorIdTableField = PM.field("sensor_id").cast(Integer.class);` and remove one argument from the method signature.

Comment: Something is wrong with the return statement because it always returns 1.0. But if I write `return calibrationFactorAPM1.value1();` it works OK.

Comment: Argh... `return calibrationFactorAPM1 != null...` and not `return calibrationFactorAPM1 == null ...`... Friday night...